# I want to assign vscode keyboard "content menu button" shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I make the Vscode "**keyboard content menu button**" passive? I want to assign other shortcuts to the keyboard "content menu button".

Comment: I'm struggling trying to understand what setting you are talking about exactly.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Do you mean the `context menu` ?

Comment: eg "ctrl + c" cancel copying. New Key Binding "menu key + c" .